# Django - Too slow database record read

Tags: python, django, performance, django-templates

I have a database with about 1500 records about one class. I'm also using jQuery Datatables to list the records.

views.py:

```
records = Animal.objects.all()
return render(request, 'animals.html', {'records': records})
```

template:

```
{% for record in records%}
<tr>
    <td>{{ record.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ record.specie }}</td>
    <td>{{ record.category}}</td>
    <td>{{ record.quantity }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But, it is very very slow. Even reducing the number of records to 100 it takes about 20~45 seconds to fully load a page. Doing the same select to find all 1500 records directly on database takes only 1 second.

As I am using jQuery DataTables to paginate and search the values, is there a way to improve this loading table time?

**EDIT:**

I used the django debug toolbar and I got these results:
[image: I used the django debug toolbar and I got these results]

Comment: without any code/context caching immediately comes to mind

Comment: without any code and concrete examples of what's going on it is difficult to tell what's wrong.

you can attempt to debug what's going on by using a tool such as django debug toolbar

Comment: why not load values from DB with ajax and endpoint that returns JSONed data???

Comment: @Kendoka, I though about that. But I'm using the jquery Datatables. But please, How would work the searching with it? I don' know

Comment: I would suggest you to add django-debug-toolbar as was previously suggested and there you can analyze what takes so much time

Comment: Hi people. Thank you for the support. I added a screenshot of what I got from django debug toolbar as you suggested.